# Set unique symbology using multiple values in ArcGIS Online using Arcade

Tags: arcgis-online, arcade

I wanted to use two values to set my unique symbology for use in a map layer in ArcGIS online. Is this possible using the custom expression option? Here is the code I am using.

Unfortunately I am only getting the later value as the result. Results should be a letter for PhaseCode followed by the placement value.

```
DomainName($feature,"PhaseCode") + $feature.Placement
if($feature.Placement == 1){
    return 'OH';
}
    else {
    return 'UG';
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this will:

1. Generate a value like `A1`, because it's using the unmodified value of `$feature.Placement`.
2. *Discard* the `A1` just generated, because it's not assigned to a variable or returned.
3. return the *exact* value specified in the `return` statement, which will be just the two characters `OH` or `UG`.

You probably want to store the return value from `DomainName` in a local variable, like this:

```
var domainNameFound = DomainName($feature,"PhaseCode");
if($feature.Placement == 1){
    return domainNameFound + 'OH';
}
else {
    return domainNameFound + 'UG';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DomainName($feature,"PhaseCode") + iif($feature.Placement == 1, 'OH', 'UG');
```

It will do the trick.